# Assign value to Html helper textbox from JSON

Tags: json, ajax, textbox, html-helper

I want to assign the value of "version" retrieved via AJAX call in JSON format to the textbox, but the below code is not working. Could anyone please help me with the same.

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) { 

var row = $("<tr />")
$("#Table").append(row);
row.append($("<td>" + '@Html.TextBox("Name", item.version , new { @class = "form-control" })' +"</td>"));

});
```